# Find all videos by codec (and not by container formats or MIME type)

Tags: command-line, video, video-encoding, codec

How can I get the list of all my videos with the used video codec?

I found some intersting commands like ***mediainfo***, ***ffmpeg*** or ***exiftool*** but they giving a lot of informations only by one video.

The most intersting command I found is ***file*** and give me this output:

```
$ file *
8 Mile (2002).avi:        RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 640 x 272, 23.98 fps, video: XviD, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
1984 (1984).avi:          RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 960 x 540, ~24 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264, audio: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (stereo, 48000 Hz)
```

And I would like an output something like this (to convert next, for sample, only videos with XviD codec):

```
~/Movies/8 Mile (2002).avi     XviD
~/Movies/1984 (1984).avi       H.264
```

NB : I'm on ***MacOS Sierra*** (10.12) but I can translate Linux commands too

Comment: IOW, do you need to pass a list of file names to another tool (i.e. automate a process) or is that output intended for human consumption (i.e. inspect the output then manually do something with some of the files) ?

Comment: @don_crissti, yes my final goal will to convert all video files with certain codecs, but in my question asked here, I just want the codecs used for each of my video files in one command line. `exiftool` works well but give me too much information. Is there a way to cut them to just have file name + codec (on one line)?

Comment: Well, you can try with `exiftool -p '$FileName $VideoCodec' -qr .` that is assuming the `VideoCodec` tag is defined - if it's not you'll have to loop over the files and use `ffprobe` or `mediainfo` - really both can print only the relevant information (if you take the time to read the man page and play with the options) - the problem is that not all video files use the same tag for the codec...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

thanks to [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) for pointing out that passing `{}` to `sh` is **always** wrong - the fix would be:

```
find ~/Movies/ -type f -iname "*.avi" -exec sh -c "echo $1; file $1 | cut -d, -f5 | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/X.264orH.264//g'" {} \;
```

---

You can try this - untested.

```
find ~/Movies/ -type f -iname "*.avi" -exec sh -c "echo {}; file '{}' | cut -d, -f5 | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/X.264orH.264//g'" \;
```

- `find`: Search for all `avi` files in `~/Movies/`
- `echo {}` print the the filename
- run `file` with that `filename`
- `cut -d, -f5` get the 5th text field cut by coma(,)
- `cut -d: -f2` get second text field cut by colon(:)
- `sed` remove spaces and possible duplicate H264 string from text

Comment: @don_crissti didn't read `mkv` in the question.